# Merge [taskbar] and [windows-taskbar]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

Look at [taskbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/taskbar):

> The Taskbar is the application switcher and launch area for Windows...

Look at [windows-taskbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-taskbar):

> ...a taskbar is a bar displayed on an edge of a GUI desktop that is used to launch and monitor running applications...

Their wikis are *nearly **switched*** in OS-specificity!

Stats:

```
[taskbar] x547
[windows-taskbar] x92
[taskbar] [windows-taskbar] x31
```

Approximately one-third of questions tagged [windows-taskbar] already have the [taskbar] tag.

#### I propose [windows-taskbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-taskbar) be merged with [taskbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/taskbar).

Comment: I think it should be backwards

Comment: @Braiam, why? Not only Windows has taskbars (although they usually go by different names on other platforms, not all users may know the "official" name for their system).

Comment: "I propose windows-taskbar be burninated into taskbar." I say that is more safe using windows-taskbar instead. In fact, taskbars are pretty OS/DE specific.

Answer (score 1):

I went through all the questions tagged [taskbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/taskbar) to make sure there was nothing contra-indicating this merge.

There were only a couple of [taskbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/taskbar) questions that *weren't* about Windows, and these are now retagged:

- [method may produce 'java.lang.NullPointerException'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34794052/method-may-produce-java-lang-nullpointerexception?noredirect=1)
- [Make action bar bigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28651102/make-action-bar-bigger?noredirect=1)
- [How do I hide the bottom status bar on the Samsung Galaxy Tab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7805350/i-need-hide-the-samsung-galaxy-tab-lower-taskbar?noredirect=1)

I closed and deleted a couple of old questions that were about configuring user-level settings in the OS (whether Windows or Linux), and were obviously not programming-related.

…And then there was this:

- [Removing icon for AppleScript script from dock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690917/applescript-show-app-in-taskbar)

  What is this? Does anyone know what this means? macOS has a Dock. Maybe you could get the terminology wrong and call that a "taskbar", but then you wouldn't *refer to the Dock in the question*. I don't know. I just retagged it anyway.

So, this is now done. The "master" tag is [taskbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/taskbar); [windows-taskbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-taskbar) is a synonym of that.
(We don't need no stinkin' prefixes.)